# I want to run 7z from a github action runner with a different user/password

Tags: 7-zip, github, user

I am running 7zip to zip some files in an app server as part of a github action. the github action runner does not have access to the server I am zipping , can I run 7z as a different user which has access to the app server? What is the syntax for it?

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to achieve. Are you trying to make the GitHub Action run a command on a remote system? How does “a different user” come into play? What operating systems are involved?

Comment: Windows 10 machine... I am trying to get github action to run a 7zip command to make a copy of a directory on a remote server and save it in a different share... doe sit amke sense?

Comment: Basically, on server A , server A\wwwroot\prod*.* is where the code I want to zip is present and I am storing teh zipped file in another server , serverb\share\backup